# Autohotkey: Modifier and Hot String for typing Acute accent

Tags: autohotkey

I want to achieve the following using AutoHotkey:

Pressing the <>-key (I already found out its key code SC056) together with the x-key, the symbol ´ (Unicode U+00B4) should be printed. If I press the a-key after that, the symbol ´ should be replaced by the accented letter á. If I press Shift+A instead, the symbol ´ should be replaced by the capital Á.

So the <>-key should work as a modifier to ease the typing of ´ and at the same time ´a resp. ´A should be auto-replaced by á resp. Á.

Since I am absolutely new to AutoHotkey, I would be very grateful for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SC056:: Send {SC056}      ; types "<"

+SC056:: Send +{SC056}    ; "Shift+SC056" types ">"

SC056 & x:: Send {U+00B4} ; types "´"


; The #If directive creates context-sensitive hotkeys:

#If (A_PriorHotKey = "SC056 & x" AND A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < 2000)

    a::Send +{Left}á  ; Press "a" within 2 seconds after "SC056 & x" to type "á"

    +a::Send +{Left}Á ; Press "Shift+a" within 2 seconds  after "SC056 & x" to type "Á"

#If                   ; turn off context sensitivity
```

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_If.htm